# CommonsMultipartFile cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: spring, jar

After upgrading spring from older version, to Spring 6.0.4
I noticed this file has moved:

[from here (Spring docs 4.3.x for CommonsMultipartFile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.28.RELEASE_to_4.3.29.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.3.29.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html)

[web on 6.0.4 doesn't have commons](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.4/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/package-summary.html)   anymore   [like 4.3.x did](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.28.RELEASE_to_4.3.29.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.3.29.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/package-summary.html#package.description)

where did this file move?

I tried including this in my pom, didn't help

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**

reducing the version of spring-web from 6.0.0 to 5.3.25 resolves the issue
BUT 5.3.25 has  [vulnerabilities](https://vulnerabilities)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <!--  version>${spring.version}</version    !-->
    <!--  some issue  CommonsMultipartFile is missing  starting with v 6.0.0 !-->
    <version> version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 13):

As per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x in Spring 6

> Several outdated Servlet-based integrations have been dropped: e.g. Apache Commons FileUpload (org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver)
> ...
> We recommend org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver for multipart file uploads

Obviously `CommonsMultipartFile` is also gone.

You can remove the `commons-fileupload` dependency from your project and in your controllers you can use `MultipartFile` that has almost the same methods as `CommonsMultipartFile` did, or `MultipartHttpServletRequest`:

```java
@RestController
class MyController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/upload)
    public ResponseEntity<SomeResult> upload(... , @RequestPart MultipartFile file1) {
        ...
    }
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/upload2")
    public ResponseEntity<SomeResult> upload2(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
                                    ...) {
        MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile("file1");
        InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm upgrading my application to spring 6. I've replaces CommansMultipartResolver with StandardServletMultipartResolver but I don't see where I can set maxFileSize or maxUploadSizePerFile. Do you know how to set that up?