# i can't use CommonsMultipartResolver in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i checked  "commons-io" and "commons-fileupload" dependencies added in my project.

but  i can't use "CommonsMultipartResolver" class and there are no suggestions,

can i know a solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnZ53.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75452756/commonsmultipartfile-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the `"commons-fileupload"` and `"commons-io"` dependencies to your project, but you still can't use the `"CommonsMultipartResolver"` class, there could be a few things that you can check:

1. make sure you have imported correct class in you java file.

   `import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;`
2. Check your project version. The `"CommonsMultipartResolver"` class is available in Spring 3.1 and later versions.
3. Check that you have included the Spring web module in your project. The `"CommonsMultipartResolver"` class is part of the Spring Web module, so make sure that you have included this module in your project dependencies.

If any solution not worked then try to clean and rebuild your project. If you continue to have issues, you may need to provide more details or seek help from stackoverflow