# File upload issues under Spring 6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to the Spring framework and encouter a file upload issues with Spring 6. According to some tutorial videos, the following code should work under spring 5 together with commons-fileupload. But according to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75452756/commonsmultipartfile-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type). The `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` is no longer available in Spring 6. Thus I used another resolver instead according to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html). But the problem was that both the `multipartFile` and the `photo` were null. I also tried adding `@RequestParam("photo")` or `@RequestPart("photo")` to the `MultipartFile photo`, it seemed that the handler was then unreached because there was not printing at all.

Here's the html form with thymeleaf syntax.

```html
<form  th:action="@{/uploadFile}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="photo">Choose a file to upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the handling method, and the resolver bean.

```java
    // I also tried using xml-based configuration, but it did not work
    @Bean
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testUpload(HttpServletRequest request, MultipartFile photo, HttpSession session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("MultipartFile: " + photo);
        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartRequest.getFile("photo");
        System.out.println("multipartRequest.getFile(\"photo\"): " + multipartFile);
        String fileName = photo.getOriginalFilename();
        String hzName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
        fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + hzName;
        ServletContext servletContext = session.getServletContext();
        String photoPath = servletContext.getRealPath("photo");
        File file = new File(photoPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        String finalPath = photoPath + File.separator + fileName;
        photo.transferTo(new File(finalPath));
        return "success";
    }
```

Searched the documentation and other related problems.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for poor english .

`org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` is no longer available in Spring 6. you can use `StandardServletMultipartResolver` class .

In order to file upload in Servlet 3.0, we need to configure a couple of pieces of the application -:
**step 1 :** 
For parsing multipart request,We need to set a **MultipartConfigElement** in our **DispatcherServletregistration**: 
**Note**: please read comments which is specify in below code

```
public class DeploymentDescriptor extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {    
     private static final String TMP_FOLDER = "/"; 
        private static final int MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 6 * 1024 * 1024; 
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {/*your code*/}
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {/*your code*/}
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {/*your code*/}
    /*register the multipartConfigElement in your dispatcher servlet. In the MultipartConfigElement object, we have configured the storage location, maximum individual file size,and the size at which the file upload progress is flushed to the storage location.*/
    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        super.customizeRegistration(registration);
        registration.setMultipartConfig(
                new MultipartConfigElement(TMP_FOLDER, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE * 2L, MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE / 2));
    }
}
```

**Step 2 :**
define the `StandardServletMultipartResolver` bean in your Spring configuration file :

```
@Bean
public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() 
{
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver(); 
}
```

**Step 3:**  Upload file :

To upload the file, you can build a simple form which contain a input type of **file** .
we need to set the encoding attribute of the form to **multipart/form-data** and the method type should be *POST*.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form:form>
```

**Step 4:**

To get the uploaded file in the controller , you can use a `MultipartFile` variable or `StandardServletMultipartResolver` .

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model, 
    HttpSession session)
        throws IOException {
    model.addAttribute("file", file);
    // i used the session object for get the context path.<br>it is totally 
    optional you can use your path for store the file . 
    String path = session.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + 
    file.getOriginalFilename();
    byte arr[] = file.getBytes();
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path);
    stream.write(arr);
    stream.close();
    return "fileUploadView";
}
```

**Step 5:**

the file will upload in your desire location . In my case my file uploaded to this location ->

**D:\7sem\Development\SpringCore.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\mvcProjects9gFileUpload**

Thank you !
I wish it will be helpful for you.